# What type of distribution can be used to describe a game with positive expected winnings?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, covariance

I've come across something I'm not too sure about. Let's say we flip a coin, heads mean we lose 1 unit, tails means we win a 1 unit. This distribution of outcomes in this would be considered normal, with the top of the bell curve at expectancy of 0 as number of trials increases.

What if we lose 1 unit for heads, but gain 5 for tails, would that still be classed as normal distribution? How would this effect variance?

Surely the large variance number would only be representive of positive results, and not the small negative swings?

Comment: The distribution of outcomes would be equidistributed, $0.5$ on each $\pm1$. The accumulated gain would _converge_ to a normal distribution.

Comment: Normal distribution but with left-skew?

Comment: Not even convergent. The expectation is $+\infty$.

Comment: If you were to analyse results of the game however, then that would converge would it not? With the top of the bell curve at expectancy of $2 per $1 bet?

Comment: *(1/2)(-1) + (1/2)(5)

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to "analyse" and when the game ends.

Comment: If this were a real game, im trying to analyse what the variance would be on such a game. How much could you expect to be up or down after playing say, 1000 turns. It stumped me because it occured to me that working out variance accurately would be difficult, since positive and negative variance are not equal.

Comment: This defines you a game: $X_i \text{ iid} \sim E(\{-1, 5\})$ and find the distribution (, expecation, variance) of
$$X = \sum_{i=1}^{1000} X_i$$

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much for your help.